# Do I have to flush a file after writing, before telling its length?

Tags: python, file

I'm writing a cross-platform program for Windows (not cygwin!) and Mac.

I'm writing to a file, and then immediately trying to get the file's new length, without closing the file first.

Do I need to flush the file after I write, in order to be guaranteed to get an accurate length?

```
with open("myfile.bin", "r+b") as f:
  f.seek(100)
  f.truncate()
  f.write("hello world")

  # Do I need to f.flush here?

  f.seek(0, 2) # seeks to end of file
  fileSize = f.tell()

  # Is fileSize guaranteed to be correct?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to call `flush`. `flush` is called to force the bytes in the buffer to be written to the stream.

In addition to that, `f.seek(0,2)` is also not required because file position is already at the end of the file after the `truncate`, `write` method call.